# how to get specific information from one line of log file

Tags: lua

I wanna get specific information from a log line by line,
the following is one line of log(the format is the same for the rest):

```
...
2010/11/22-00:00:01 - [TEST1][01.01. case1][1]
...
```

problem is I got nothing by using following code,

```
for a in str:gmatch("(%d+/%d+/%d+-%d+:%d+:%d+) - [TEST1][(%d%d.%d%d. (%C+))]") do
    print(a)
end
```

any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`-`, `[` and `]` are all magic characters in lua patterns. You need to escape them `%-`, `%[`, `%]`.

Edit: Useful addition from @hjpotter92. `.` is also "magic" and should be escaped `%.` to match only a literal `.`.

Comment: btw, what pattern should I used to get the information from the bracket, which is behind TEST1??

Comment: `for a,b in str:gmatch(....)` should do that. Each capture should be a returned argument from gmatch each loop.

Comment: `.` character as well, for safeguards.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Right. Thanks. Added. I hadn't noticed those in the pattern.